# importing a package in ES6: "Failed to resolve module specifier "vue""

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Trying to follow some Vue tutorials and I can't currently import Vue in a `.js` file and then import this file in my `index.html`. This is how I'm importing the script in my `index.html`:

```
<script src="./js/main.js" type="module"></script>
```

If I do this in my `main.js` file:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
```

I get the following error in the browser console:

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "vue". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".

If my import line to:

```
import Vue from '../../node_modules/vue';
```

Then I get a different error:

> http://localhost:63342/vue-official-tutorial/node_modules/vue
>   net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: are you working with webpack or vue cli 3 ...?

Comment: @boussadjrabrahim - Thanks. To be honest I'm not very sure. I did do `npm install vue` to be able to do `import Vue from 'vue'` without ESLint complaining. But I don't recall having installed `vue cli`. I do have a `package.json` file in the project's root folder that includes `vue` as a dependency after I've installed `vue` with `npm`

Comment: You just show the import of Vue. How did you load the vue.js script in your HTML?

Comment: I've had a similar issue and have asked a question about it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72368150/how-to-do-module-resolution-when-an-npm-package-contains-multiple-namespaces-sub

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## UPDATE (2020-05-10)

[Using ES6 modules without Webpack](https://vuejsdevelopers.com/2019/02/04/vue-es-module-browser-build/)

---

If you are working with **ES6** then you **should NOT** manually inserting your `main.js` into `index.html` - this will be handled by **Webpack**. Actually, the simplest tutorial for Vue goes like this:

1. npm install -g vue-cli
2. vue init webpack my_project
3. npm run dev (and start developing - result is available on http://localhost:8080)
4. npm run build (result is available inside the `./dist` folder of your project

Also, you should import Vue like this

> import Vue from 'vue';

and not like this

> import Vue from '../../node_modules/vue';

#### EDIT

Okay, if you insist on going through the beginners' path and not using Webpack and single-file Vue components - then you should start like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />
    <title>My beginners project</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/css/styles.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="app">
      <router-view></router-view>
    </div>
    <!-- templates for your components -->
    <template id="login">
      <div>test</div>
    </template>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-router@3.0.1/dist/vue-router.js"></script>
    <!-- code for your components -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/app/login.js"></script>
    <!-- Vue Root component should be last -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/app/app.js"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

And your `/app/app.js` will look like this:

```js
var badRoute = Vue.component('bad-route', {
    template: '<div id="bad_route"><h1>Page Not Found</h1><p>Sorry, but the page you were trying to view does not exist.</p></div>'
});
var vue_router = new VueRouter({
    base: '/app'
    , mode: 'hash'
    , routes: [{
        path: '/'
        , redirect: '/login'
    }, {
        path: '/login'
        , component: loginForm
        , name: 'LOGIN'
    }, {
        path: '*', // should be last, otherwise matches everything
        component: badRoute
        , name: 'NOT FOUND'
    }]
});
// Main application
var vue_app = new Vue({
        router: vue_router
    , })
    .$mount('#app');
```

And your `/app/login.js` component will look like this:

```js
var loginForm = Vue.component('login-form', {
    template: '#login', // should match the ID of template tag
    data: function() {
        var a = {
            username: ''
            , password: ''
        , };
        return a;
    }
    , methods: {}
});
```

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm sure there's something I'm missing but I don't get how this answers my question. If I simply remove the manual import of the `main.js` script tag, then...nothing happens.

Comment: Also: I am doing `import Vue from 'vue'` but getting a syntax error on the JS file "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier" in the line where I import it like this.

Comment: I will try to clarify the steps. On step 1 you install Vue-CLI tool globally on your computer. On step 2 you use the tool to scaffold an empty Vue project using the official Webpack template. On step 3 you start a development web server so that you can immediately see how your new web applications looks like (by opening the specified URL in your browser). Here you write your code in `main.js`, then in `App.vue` and then in your other single-file Vue components (if you create such ones). On step 4 you build your project and deploy `./dist` folder onto your hosting.

Comment: Sorry. I still don't understand why what I'm doing as per the above isn't working. I don't have vue-cli installed because the official tutorial explicitly states that beginners shouldn't go that route. Why can't I use `import Vue from 'vue'` in my `main.js` file and simply have that render correctly? (I'm not "complaining" to you, this was my actual question)

Comment: This answer is correct and complete.  My answer (below?) may help clarify the issue.

Comment: Webpack is no longer necessary with ES modules.

Comment: I would also think that webpack is not necessary with ES modules. But for vue i also get this error. Maybe it's loading the wrong type of vue module from node-modules?

Comment: @Catweazle Without Vue-CLI you need to load `vue.js` rather than `vue.runtime.js`

Comment: @zerohedge If you work with modules but without Vue-CLI then you should read this article - https://vuejsdevelopers.com/2019/02/04/vue-es-module-browser-build/

Comment: Thanks @zerhedge! Following the input from the artile, I was able to get it working by 1/ cp node_modules/vue/dist/vue.esm.browser.js vue.js 2/ in my module: import Vue from './vue.js'

Comment: I don't think this answers the question. The answer from @evgeny actually does.

Comment: Has anyone other answer? , iinstalled all of this and still have that error

Answer (score 41):

As of June 2020

The way you can use ES modules **in your Browser** directly is this:

1. Use the ESM version of your dependencies (the one that has `import` instead of `require`).

   For example, Vue ESM version is available at: `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/3.2.41/vue.esm-browser.prod.js`
2. Make your browser work with the experimental `importmap` feature.

   update 2022:  major browsers now [support](https://caniuse.com/import-maps) Import maps

   For older versions of Chrome this is under `chrome://flags#enable-experimental-productivity-features`
   (latest Chrome versions moved this under `chrome://flags#enable-experimental-web-platform-features`)
3. Create an `importmap` in your HTML file.

   It only works with inline `<script>` tags at the moment in Chrome. For example:

```html
<script type="importmap">
  { "imports": {
      "vue":        "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/3.2.41/vue.esm-browser.prod.js",
      "vue-router": "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue-router/4.1.5/vue-router.esm-browser.min.js"
  } }
</script>
```

4. Load your own code as an ESM module.

```html
<script type="module" src="./main.js"></script>
```

5. In your own scripts, and the scripts that you import - you can now successfully import from named modules.

[Import Maps Documentation](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#import-maps)

---

Full example:

```html
<html>
<body class="app">

<script type="importmap">
  { "imports": {
      "vue":               "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/3.2.41/vue.esm-browser.prod.js",
      "vue-router":        "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue-router/4.1.5/vue-router.esm-browser.min.js",
      "@vue/devtools-api": "https://unpkg.com/@vue/devtools-api@6.4.5/lib/esm/index.js"
  } }
</script>

<script type="module">
  import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router'
  import { createApp } from 'vue'

  const app = createApp({ template: 'Hello world.' })
  const router = createRouter({
    routes: [{ path: '/:pathMatch(.*)*', component: app }],
    history: createWebHistory()
  })
  app.use(router)

  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => app.mount('.app'));
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Note to readers: [**Firefox** currently seems to have a bug](https://discourse.threejs.org/t/solved-importmaps-broken-on-firefox-which-now-supports-importmaps/48413/6) where the `type="importmap"` script must come first to work.  Check how you've ordered things if import mapping works fine for you on Chrome, etc. and yet Firefox gives you the error, "The specifier 'vue' was a bare specifier, but was not remapped to anything."

Answer (score 3):

You can only use "import vue..." if you are using the CLI and webpack, etc.

If you are using Vue directly in a web page, you can follow the instructions at https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/installation.html#Direct-lt-script-gt-Include and include a line like this in your HTML file:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
```

Do this before you import your own script, and then `Vue` will be defined and you don't need to import it again. Import your script without the "module" attribute. In the script, you can run:

```
var x = new Vue({ 
  el: '#myApp',
  ... all the other stuff ...
})
```

This assumes that somewhere on your HTML page you have:

```
<div id=myApp></div>
```

Answer (score -3):

Moving to TypeScript resolved the issue for me.

```
// index.html
<script type="module" src="/src/main.ts"></script>


// tsconfig.json
{
  "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/tsconfig",
  "extends": "@vue/tsconfig/tsconfig.json",
  "include": ["*.d.ts", "src/**/*", "src/**/*.vue"],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "module": "ES2022",
    "strict": true,
    "target": "es2022",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./src/*"]
    },
    "types": ["vitest/globals"]
  },
  "references": [
    {
      "path": "./tsconfig.vite-config.json"
    }
  ]
}


// tsconfig.vite-config.json
{
  "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/tsconfig",
  "extends": "@vue/tsconfig/tsconfig.json",
  "include": ["vite.config.*", "vitest.config.*"],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "composite": true,
    "types": ["node"]
  }
}


// vite.config.ts
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
import path from 'path'
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'

export default defineConfig(({ mode }) => {
  return {
    plugins: [vue()],
    resolve: {
      alias: {
        '@': path.resolve(__dirname, './src'),
      },
    },
  }
})
```