# What it means "require is not defined" in JS and how the libraries are available for the browser?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I installed through npm in WebStorm this [library](https://github.com/electerious/basicScroll)

```
npm install basicscroll
```

The IDE highlights the words of the package, and everything seems fine until I try to see the project in the browser:

The console gives me this issue:

```
applicative.js:15 Uncaught ReferenceError: basicScroll is not defined
    at applicative.js:15
    at NodeList.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at applicative.js:6
```

So I added at the beginning of my JS file this statement:

```
const basicScroll = require('basicscroll')
```

The result this time is that the library remains highlighted, but the method called on it not. And in browser this is the error prompt by the console:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
```

I checked my `node_modules` directory, I can see the sub-directory, so I think the installation process went right. I also checked the `package.json` file:

```
"dependencies": {
    "basicscroll": "^3.0.2",
    [...]
```

I honestly don't know where the problem is. I'm new to web development and online I found that the webpack module-bounder could help me, but I don't even know where to start. What is wrong ?
Thank'you !

Comment: Test with `import basicScroll from 'basicscroll'`

Comment: I get this error [Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "basicscroll". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".]

I even added a slash before '/basicscroll' I get this error:
[GET http://localhost:63342/basicscroll net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)]

Comment: You might have missing aliases for import in your config, if you import from './node_modules/basicscroll' it could work

Comment: is this in node or the browser? if it's in the browser you would need to transpile your code before running, the browser has no concept of npm modules.

Comment: This guy had exactly the same issue (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52612446/importing-a-package-in-es6-failed-to-resolve-module-specifier-vue). I think that @DanStarns has the closest answer. This errors are displayed in the browser, what you mean exactly for 'transpile' your code exactly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Client on node: Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19059580/client-on-node-uncaught-referenceerror-require-is-not-defined)

Comment: @WebStormer Transpiling 'taking source code written in one language and transforming into another' you can use tools such as [parcel](https://parceljs.org) to bundle modules & [babel](https://babeljs.io/) to transpile code.

Answer (score 3):

It seems like you are trying to use server-side code in a client-side environment. As far as I know `require` is a NodeJS thing and doesn't exist in the browser.

Your easiest solution would be to use a `<script>` tag in your html to import the files you need. Something like `<script src="dist/basicScroll.min.js"></script>`

This answer mentions some other tools you could use to manage that sort of thing: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19059825/1801137