# Import Tweakpane as a npm module

Tags: npm, ecmascript-6

I'm very new to NPM, bundlers and ES6.

I'm trying to use [Tweakpane](https://cocopon.github.io/tweakpane/) in a project, thus I did install it with NPM.

Then I import it with:

```
import { Tweakpane } from "./node_modules/tweakpane/dist/tweakpane.js";
```

But I get the following error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module './node_modules/tweakpane/dist/tweakpane.js' does not provide an export named 'Tweakpane'
```

I find it hard to believe that Tweakpane doesn't have a ES6 export functionnality.
What do I miss here?

Answer (score 1):

I assume the import cannot be [destructured](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#object_destructuring). Try to import it directly:

```js
import Tweakpane from "tweakpane";
```

Also, there is no need to specify the complete path into the `node_modules` folder.

Comment: Thanks. Doesn't work neither with non destructured import though: Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module './node_modules/tweakpane/dist/tweakpane.js' does not provide an export named 'default'

Comment: And when not specifying the full path: Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "tweakpane". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".

Comment: @bolino Did you paste the code exactly as I wrote it? I just tested it [and it works](https://imgur.com/a/Dg4oR45).

Comment: I did. I should maybe specify that I'm not using any bundler. I would have like not to use one and import my main JS file manually, but according to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52612446/importing-a-package-in-es6-failed-to-resolve-module-specifier-vue, it seems it is not possible?