# Can't import from web

Tags: javascript, three.js

I tried to import modules from web:

```js
import * as THREE from 'https://unpkg.com/three@0.130.1/build/three.module.js';
import { OrbitControls } from 'https://unpkg.com/three@0.130.1/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls';
import { GLTFLoader } from 'https://unpkg.com/three@0.130.1/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js';
```

but i get

`Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "three". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".`

Comment: Is this browser code or server-side code?

Comment: code is client-side

Answer (score 1):

I believe the first import works fine, but the example files have code that looks like

```js
import { ... } from 'three'
```

If you want to keep your three import as is, I think you need to download the examples and modify them to instead import from `'https://unpkg.com/three@0.130.1/build/three.module.js'`.

Alternatively, there is [an experimental `importmap` feature](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62282239/7797661) that might let you define a map from 'three' to the appropriate URL.

Alternatively, this is why we typically use bundlers like Webpack to assemble all imports together.

Comment: You can use modules in browser: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import

Comment: @jabaa - you can, but they have to provide actual URLs when they, in turn, try to import something. They can’t use Node.js style module resolution.

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules

Comment: @Quentin Yes, you have to import them in the HTML file using the URL and import them using the module name. But _"I think you need to download the examples and modify them to instead import"_ is wrong. You don't need bundlers. This answer is a comment at best. From a good/helpful answer I would expect an explanation how to import a module in a browser with HTML code.