# Using NPM package shows "Error: cannot use import statement outside a module"

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I am trying to use `Typed.js` library and I installed it using NPM. I used a simple example in my "main.js" file and linked it with `<script src="./main.js"></script>`. The error kept showing `Error: Cannot using import outside a module"`. So I used `<script type="module" src="./main.js"></script>`. But now it shows `Failed to resolve module specifier......Relative path references must start with "/", "./", "../"`

I copied the code from the official `Typed.js` documentation.

```js
// Can also be included with a regular script tag
import Typed from 'typed.js';

var options = {
  strings: ['<i>First</i> sentence.', '&amp; a second sentence.'],
  typeSpeed: 40
};

var typed = new Typed('.element', options);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1 class="element"></h1>

  <script src="./main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you share your `main.js` here?

Answer (score 0):

why are you trying to import script in main.js its not HTML thats syntax error. You need to type in like let your_varible_name = require("Typed.js") to get it running in node. If you intend to use in front end then use it in HTML like that. It will work there.

Comment: I am confused. In the official docs, they use the "import" statement. And you said use it in "front end", how can i use it in HTML??

Comment: there is ES6 syntax out there that let you use "import var_name from package" but if you are not using that. you must use let var_name = require("your_installed_package.js"). I think thats you are trying to do. If you are developing a webpage then you use HTML there you write like <script src="your_package_url or directory"></script>.

Comment: oh sorry you added a code. i didnot see that. yes that line "import Typed from 'typed.js'" will probably generate the error in js file because you are not using ES6. change that back to let Typed = require("typed.js"). thats it. it will be working fine.

Comment: it says "require is not defined"

Comment: ok i get it. you are importing typed.js in main.js and then use main in HTML. thats a prob. you cannot import a package in another file you are importing to HTML. import it separately in your HTML file. did i get you correct. what is your main.js. did you try importing typed in main.

Comment: ugh thank god, finally, yes importing the node module separately worked. I got confused because I am used to importing modules in React directly in the file.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use it without npm consider to import it directly to your html instead:`<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/typed.js@2.0.12"></script>`
Or this might also help: [Failed to resolve module specifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52612446/importing-a-package-in-es6-failed-to-resolve-module-specifier-vue)

Comment: But I want to use it with npm. And I don't know anything about webpack yet. And, I guess I am confused because I used the "import" statement in "React" which uses webpack. But what if im just using vanilla JS? Do I have to use Webpack if I'm using npm packages in vanilla jS?

Comment: If you want to stick with React. Then import it in your main.js or index.js (whatever your application entry point) but don't need to manually import your main.js to your index.html (Let webpack handle it).

import Typed from 'typed.js';

Comment: So to use it in a Vanilla JS project (no frontend framework or anything), I have to utilize Webpack to use NPM packages? I'm not using any framework.. My only JS file was main.js as shown above.

Comment: No. To use NPM packages you only need to install nodejs. Webpack is a bundler tool. In some cases, you don't need nodejs if there is a CDN available, then just import directly to your index.html file. In your case it's <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/typed.js@2.0.12"></script>

Comment: okay, dunno what's wrong with using npm, but i guess i'll use CDN for now