# Javascript, Node.js and browser: Import from folder does not work in web app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, import, web-applications

This import of a folder (@terra-money/terra.js/)

`import {LCDClient, Coin} from "@terra-money/terra.js"`

works without problems when running the file with node.js

But when I want to use the same expression in a web app I get the error message

`"Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "@terra-money/terra.js". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../"."`

... so the problem seems to be that the import does not point to a single .js-file, right? Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: `import {LCDClient, Coin} from "@terra-money/terra.js"` doesn't import a _folder_ with that name, but a _package_ (on node that is). For code used in a browser, you'll need a bundler.

Comment: Ok, I see. Can you point me in the direction what to use? I tried Browserify and used "require" instead of "import", but ended up with the same problem that Browserify threw a File not found error

Comment: I use webpack as a part of tools like create-react-app.

Comment: thank you very much. I tried webpack, but it didn't work unfortunately.

Comment: I’m sure it might, but the comment doesn’t explain why. Do you have a package.json file?

Comment: Yes, it says this: `{
  "name": "webpack-demo",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "private": "true",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "^5.65.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.9.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@terra-money/terra.js": "^3.0.2",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21"
  }
}`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [importing a package in ES6: "Failed to resolve module specifier "vue""](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52612446/importing-a-package-in-es6-failed-to-resolve-module-specifier-vue)

Comment: Thank @evolutionxbox, first the Importmap solution looked good but then I noticed it uses some sort of variable declaration pointing to single .js-files (which wouldnt work in my case because"terra.js" is the folder name) ... but then I found a `webpack.config.js` in the folder, copied it in the project path so I could run `npx webpack --config webpack.config.js` but that threw an error: "Failed to load '/Users/coding/webpack-demo/webpack.config.js' config
[webpack-cli] Error: Cannot find module 'tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin'" ... any ideas what to do from here?

Comment: @evolutionxbox I used `npm install tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin` and then again tried `npx webpack --config webpack.config.js`... this time a new error and I cant figure out what to do with it: Failed to load '/Users/coding/webpack-demo/webpack.config.js' config
[webpack-cli] Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'tsconfig.json'

Comment: Do you have a file called tsconfig.json?

Comment: yes, there is such a file in the github repo

Comment: I copied the tsconfig.json in the project directory but that doesnt help ... should I place it elsewhere or do I have to specify the file location somewhere in the webpack configfile?