# ES6 import statements not working on web server

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, ably-realtime

My imports work fine within my javascript file, but they do not work when I start the webserver. I can access the functions of the imported module as expected, but the import statement itself fails when I boot up the nodejs server.

I added the following import statement without error to the top of a javascript class

```
import * as Ably from 'ably';
```

My HTML file has this at the end of the body tag

```
<script src="./app.js" type="module"></script>
```

I get the following error from inspect element (no errors in vscode)

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "ably". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".
```

I tried changing the file path

```
import * as Ably from './node_modules/ably/ably.js';
```

but this gave me 404 errors

```
GET http://localhost:3000/node_modules/ably/ably.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

Comment: Look at https://github.com/ably/ably-js/pull/704

Answer (score 0):

Try using `<script src="https://cdn.ably.com/lib/ably.min-1.js"></script>` in HTML file
instead of import. Also, check this thread, looks similar to your problem [Failed to resolve module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52612446/importing-a-package-in-es6-failed-to-resolve-module-specifier-vue)

Comment: When I do this,  my js file doesn't recognize Ably at all and I can't use it(even when I removed the module tag)