# How to do module resolution when an npm package contains multiple namespaces/submodules

Tags: javascript, module, node-modules, package.json

A project I am working with is using this package: `https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ethersproject/abstract-provider`
within an SDK we are building..

After installation, the SDK `node_modules` folder contains the `@ethersproject` directory which contains an `abstract-provider` directory as well as multiple other directories, each their own namespace with separate `package.json` files.

We use the code in the sdk as follows:
`import { Provider } from '@ethersproject/abstract-provider';`
and this works fine for webpack based projects which import our SDK (such as a React app using create-react-app).

When I want to use our SDK in a project which DOESN'T use a bundler such as webpack (such as a very simple frontend pulling in our sdk with `importmap` as here: https://github.com/unegma/rainprotocol__verify-gating), we are getting an error:

`Failed to resolve module specifier "@ethersproject/abstract-provider". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".`

I'm assuming this is because our SDK doesn't know how to resolve `@ethersproject/abstract-provider` because `abstract-provider` is a submodule of `@ethersproject` (which isn't even a module itself).

What is the way to solve this issue? Do we need to create a `decs.d.ts` file in our SDK root which contains something like: `declare module "@ethersproject/abstract-provider;` or is there a different way to do this?

Comment: Is this a javascript or a typescript question? `.d.ts` files apply to typescript but you have the question tagged as javascript.

Comment: Good question @Ouroborus, I can't say I understand enough about what happens during typescript compilation to be able to say, either way, I'm using javascript for my own repo, but the sdk is built in typescript. We think we have fixed it by doing this: https://github.com/beehive-innovation/rain-sdk/commit/06b998b79126a9dbdf0a6a0382b7385340d4426f

Comment: Does this answer your question? [importing a package in ES6: "Failed to resolve module specifier "vue""](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52612446/importing-a-package-in-es6-failed-to-resolve-module-specifier-vue)