# Not able to use neither require nor import in browser extension popup.js

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, import, html-to-pdf

I am making a browser extension that gets the code of a div and converts it into html. I have tried doing this with jspdf , html2pdf, but none of that worked perfectly.

So i used html-to-pdfmake but i cannot import it in my popup.js

```
var pdfMake = require("pdfmake/build/pdfmake");
var pdfFonts = require("pdfmake/build/vfs_fonts");
pdfMake.vfs = pdfFonts.pdfMake.vfs;
var htmlToPdfmake = require("html-to-pdfmake");
```

- If imported like this it gives me the error

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
```

if imported using "import"

```
import pdfMake from "pdfmake/build/pdfmake";
import pdfFonts from "pdfmake/build/vfs_fonts";
pdfMake.vfs = pdfFonts.pdfMake.vfs;
import htmlToPdfmake from "html-to-pdfmake";
```

it gives me

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "pdfmake/build/pdfmake". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".
```

Any ideas how to import it . The package doesn't have any tutorials as it is unpopular.

I have tried

```
import htmlToPdfmake from "./node_modules/html-to-pdfmake";
```

but that doesn't work as well.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [importing a package in ES6: "Failed to resolve module specifier "vue""](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52612446/importing-a-package-in-es6-failed-to-resolve-module-specifier-vue)

Comment: Either use a bundler or configure your web server to serve `node_modules` and use the native module system or a module loader. There are dozens or hundreds of ways to use modules. Do some research, choose one way and try it. Then, ask a specific question.

Comment: Load like script can help you? 

`<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.2.2/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.2.2/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html-to-pdfmake/0.2.0/html-to-pdfmake.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Either use webpack or add a file extension `.js` and use relative path for the native ES import to work.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From where do you want load this modules?

Maybe this will help you [How to import ES6 modules in content script for Chrome Extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48104433/how-to-import-es6-modules-in-content-script-for-chrome-extension)