# "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'defineComponent')" when loading Vuetify3 from CDN in importmap

Tags: vuejs3, cdn, vuetifyjs3, import-maps

According to [CDN](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/installation/#cdn) section of the document Get started with Vuetify3, I've prepared CDN links of vuetify on `index.html` and calling `createVuetify()` on `main.js` as follows:

***index.html***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Vite App</title>
    <!-- https://stackoverflow.com/a/62282239/11073131 -->
    <script type="importmap">
      {
        "imports": {
          "vue": "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@3/dist/vue.esm-browser.prod.js",
          "vue-router": "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue-router@4/dist/vue-router.esm-browser.js",
          "@vue/devtools-api": "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@vue/devtools-api@6/lib/esm/index.js"
        }
      }
    </script>

    <!--vuetify-->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3.1.14/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3.1.14/dist/vuetify.min.js">

</script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script type="module" src="/src/main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**main.js**

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import Home from '/src/views/Home.vue'
import About from '/src/views/About.vue'
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router'

import './assets/main.css'

// router
const routes = [
  { path: '/', component: Home },
  { path: '/about', component: About },
]

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(),
  routes, // short for `routes: routes`
})

// vuetify
const { createVuetify } = Vuetify
const vuetify = createVuetify()

createApp(App).use(router).use(vuetify).mount('#app')
```

Run `yarn dev` and read this site from the browser, this main.js get the error of

> Cannot read properties of undefined  (reading 'defineComponent')

[image]

I have no idea what was wrong or lacked steps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The .js version of Vuetify expects Vue to be available in the global scope, but you are importing it as a named ESM import.

Try importing Vuetify as ESM module as well, check https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3.1.14/dist/ for the correct sources:

```html
<script type="importmap">
  {
    "imports": {
      "vue": "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@3/dist/vue.esm-browser.prod.js",
      "vue-router": "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue-router@4/dist/vue-router.esm-browser.js",
      "@vue/devtools-api": "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@vue/devtools-api@6/lib/esm/index.js",
      "vuetify": "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3.1.14/dist/vuetify.esm.js"
    }
  }
</script>
```

Then you can import it like other modules:

```
import { createVuetify } from 'vuetify'
const vuetify = createVuetify()
```

Where the name has to be the key from the importmap.

---

Note that `importmap` is a pretty new feature and there seem to be bugs around the issue in Firefox version 112.0.1, but not in 113.0b5. Same in Chrome version 110.0.5481.177, but not in 112.0.5615.49.

---

This works when I load it from a local webserver:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Vite App</title>
    <script type="importmap">
      {
        "imports": {
          "vue": "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@3/dist/vue.esm-browser.prod.js",
          "@vue/devtools-api": "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@vue/devtools-api@6/lib/esm/index.js",
          "vuetify": "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3.1.14/dist/vuetify.esm.js"
        }
      }
    </script>
    <script type="module" src="/main.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3.1.14/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

```
import { createApp, ref } from 'vue'
import { createVuetify } from 'vuetify'

const vuetify = createVuetify()

const App = {
  template: `
      <v-app>
        <v-main>
          <v-switch v-model="switcher"/> {{ switcher }}
        </v-main>
      </v-app>
  `,
  data(){
    return {
      switcher: ref(true)
    }    
  }
}

createApp(App).use(vuetify).mount('#app')
```

Comment: How can I change my ``main.js`` to import ``vuetify`` defined above to use in ``createApp(App).use(router).use(vuetify).mount('#app')``?

Comment: Thank you for your kindly answer. But this lead to the error of "Failed to resolve import "vuetify" from "src/main.js". Does the file exist?".

Comment: Interesting about the difference of result. My reproducing environment is available at https://github.com/UedaTakeyuki/MyVue3Scaffold2. With this repository, error is occuring.

Comment: Looks like there are still huge differences with `importmap` between browsers. In Firefox (112.0.1), there seems to be a race-condition, where `main.js` is executed before the imports are available. In Chromium, it seems to run stable. Running your "MyVue3Scaffold2" gives me an error on the imports of the `.vue` files (App.vue, Home.vue, About.vue) and the import of main.css, but once I remove those, it is running. Using Firefox Developer edition (113.0b5), it works too. What browser are you using? Does it work when you switch to Chrome?

Comment: Hi Moritz, Thank you for your kind help! I'm using Chrome 110.0.5481.177 on Mac. Also, I've confirmed on Firefox 109.0.1 (64-bit) occurs same error.

Comment: It is working with Chromium Version 112.0.5615.49. Seems like you will have to update your browser.

Comment: Hi Moritz, thank you so much for your kind and devoted help. I believe you are right. I'm sorry with the latest version of Chrome, another phenomenon that hides the original phenomenon appears as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76259677/vite-cant-resolve-path-from-importmap and block confirmation. After fixing these I will be back here. I'm so sorry for a long time bother you.

Comment: Works well! Thank you, Moritz! I really appreciate your help!