# Vite Dev Server throws error when resolving external path from importmap

Tags: vuejs3, vite

## Environment

- Chrome: 113.0.5672.92
- Vite: 4.3.6

## Reproducing Environment

https://github.com/UedaTakeyuki/MyVue3Scaffold2

## What is happen

In my Vue3 application, I tried to use libraries from CDN with following **importmap** script in the index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Vite App</title>
    <!-- https://stackoverflow.com/a/62282239/11073131 -->
    <script type="importmap">
      {
        "imports": {
          "vue": "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@3/dist/vue.esm-browser.prod.js",
          "vuetify": "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3.1.14/dist/vuetify.esm.js",
          "vue-router": "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue-router@4/dist/vue-router.esm-browser.js",
          "@vue/devtools-api": "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@vue/devtools-api@6/lib/esm/index.js"
        }
      }
    </script>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3.1.14/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script type="module" src="/src/main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

And set vuetify as **external** at the vite.config.ts file:

```
  build: {
    rollupOptions: {
      external: [
        'vue',
        'vuetify',
        'vue-router',
      ],
```

Then import **vuetify** at main.js as follows:

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import Home from '/src/views/Home.vue'
import About from '/src/views/About.vue'
import { createRouter, createWebHistory, createWebHashHistory } from 'vue-router'
import { createVuetify } from 'vuetify'
```

Then, run LocalServer and brows it, the error `Failed to resolve import "vuetify" from "src/main.js".` occurred.

[image]

## Question

First of all, Does vite support the **importmap** by design? Or are there any wrong or mistaken steps in my App? I'm totally confused, any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a current [issue in Vite](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/6582), where dev server tries to resolve inputs it shouldn't. Looks like they are working on it. There is a [proposed workaround](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/6393#issuecomment-1006819717) where you create a plugin that ignores given imports. I tried it out and it does work.

Just add the [code from the workaround](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/6393#issuecomment-1006819717) to your vite.config.js:

```
function viteIgnoreStaticImport(importKeys) {
  return {
    name: "vite-plugin-ignore-static-import",
    enforce: "pre",
    // 1. insert to optimizeDeps.exclude to prevent pre-transform
    config(config) {
      config.optimizeDeps = {
        ...(config.optimizeDeps ?? {}),
        exclude: [...(config.optimizeDeps?.exclude ?? []), ...importKeys],
      };
    },
    // 2. push a plugin to rewrite the 'vite:import-analysis' prefix
    configResolved(resolvedConfig) {
      const VALID_ID_PREFIX = `/@id/`;
      const reg = new RegExp(
        `${VALID_ID_PREFIX}(${importKeys.join("|")})`,
        "g"
      );
      resolvedConfig.plugins.push({
        name: "vite-plugin-ignore-static-import-replace-idprefix",
        transform: (code) =>
          reg.test(code) ? code.replace(reg, (m, s1) => s1) : code,
      });
    },
    // 3. rewrite the id before 'vite:resolve' plugin transform to 'node_modules/...'
    resolveId: (id) => {
      if (importKeys.includes(id)) {
        return { id, external: true };
      }
    },
  };
}
```

and then add the plugin to your config:

```
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
     vue(),
     viteIgnoreStaticImport(["vuetify"]) // <---- pass in the modules you want to ignore
  ],
  ...
```

And that is all. Just don't forget to remove it once the issue is resolved by Vite.