# How to import a library only if it exists in Vite?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, shared-libraries, vite, importerror

Let's say in my library I want to import an animation library only if the developer has installed it.

Pseudo code as follows:

```js
let utility = null

// If the library returns the library location as a string
if (Boolean(require.resolve('animation-library'))) {
  import('animation-library').then(library => utility = library.helper)
}
```

Currently, on Vite (Rollup.js) you get a warning, as the import is analyzed on compilation.

```
The above dynamic import cannot be analyzed by Vite.
See https://github.com/rollup/plugins/tree/master/packages/dynamic-import-vars#limitations for supported dynamic import formats. If this is intended to be left as-is, you can use the /* @vite-ignore */ comment inside the import() call to suppress this warning.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76259677/vite-dev-server-throws-error-when-resolving-external-path-from-importmap